# Rest WebService with signed requests in Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, dsa

I'm currently implementing a rest web service with Spring+Java+Tomcat and a cmd client to access it. The most important requirement is to restrict the usage to authenticated users - encryption isn't that important.

Because I can't guarantee that the service is accessed via TLS, I can't use Basic Authentication with username and password.

My idea is to do the following:

1. Get a nonce from the web service - that's changed after each request
2. Calculate a signature with DSA of (request + nonce)
3. Add signature to HTTP header and check it in the web service

How I would create the signature:

```
// To generate the keys
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
keyGen.initialize(1024, random);
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

// Per request
Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");
dsa.initSign(pair.getPrivate);
dsa.update(...)
byte[] signature = dsa.sign();
```

To check the signature:

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");
sig.initVerify(pubKey);
sig.update(...)
boolean ok = sig.verify(sigToVerify);
```

I hear so much about don't implement your own security, which is why I would like to know whether other people see something I don't.

Does someone see a major problem with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the nonce you get from the web service must be cryptographically secure (unpredictable) and used only one time to avoid replay attacks.

Then, there is nothing wrong with this approach, as soon as the web service stores the public key from the client and is able to verify its authenticity.

Moreover, one drawback to consider, is signature verification performance cost. (see: [Statistical data about the performance of various encryption algorithms](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9215/statistical-data-about-the-performance-of-various-encryption-algorithms))